# How to group attendances data by time and type?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with code that would group attendance data.
Usually, in cases where arrival and departure are on the same day, it's not a problem to group the attendance.
The problem becomes if I have a "night shift": arriving at 10pm and leaving at 06am the next day. In that case, I would like to have a new group of attendances. And than If there are any attendance entries for the next day as well (later than the first check-out for that day), I want to combine them into a new group.

```
$attendances = [

//Group 1

{
    "id": 1,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-24",
    "time": "11:00:00",
    "status": "arrival"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-24",
    "time": "14:00:00",
    "status": "departure"
},

//Group 2

{
    "id": 3,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-24",
    "time": "22:00:00",
    "status": "arrival"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-25",
    "time": "06:00:00",
    "status": "departure"
},

// Group 3

{
    "id": 5,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-25",
    "time": "10:00:00",
    "status": "arrival"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "attendance_date": "2023-08-25",
    "time": "18:00:00",
    "status": "departure"
}
```

]

My current code for grouping array is this and it only works in some cases.

```
        $currentDate = null;
        $groupedAttendances = [];
        $currentGroup = [];

        foreach ($attendances as $attendance) {
            if ($attendance->attendance_date !== $currentDate) {
                // New attendance_date encountered, create a new group
                $currentDate = $attendance->attendance_date;
                if (!empty($currentGroup)) {
                    $groupedAttendances[] = $currentGroup;
                }
                $currentGroup = [$attendance];
            } else {
                // Adding to the current group
                $currentGroup[] = $attendance;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($currentGroup)) {
            $groupedAttendances[] = $currentGroup;
        }
```

Comment: Please show what exact result you want, based on the given input data.

Comment: If the source data comes from a database perhaps using a properly crafted sql query would be easier than trying to mangle json to fit?

Comment: @ador What is defining a group? The order, so the first two belong together, the 3rd and 4th belong together, etc.? Or the id (the lowest two ids belong together, etc.)? Or the time (but what if dates and times of two groups overlap)? Or something else? Currently only your comment lines group the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I was unclear. But I managed to get the wanted result.

Example data from database:

```
$data = [
            (object) [
                "id" => 1,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-24",
                "time" => "11:00:00",
                "status" => "arrival",
            ],
            (object) [
                "id" => 2,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-24",
                "time" => "14:00:00",
                "status" => "departure",
            ],
            (object) [
                "id" => 3,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-24",
                "time" => "22:00:00",
                "status" => "arrival",
            ],
            (object) [
                "id" => 4,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-25",
                "time" => "06:00:00",
                "status" => "departure",
            ],
            (object) [
                "id" => 5,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-25",
                "time" => "10:00:00",
                "status" => "arrival",
            ],
            (object) [
                "id" => 6,
                "attendance_date" => "2023-08-25",
                "time" => "18:00:00",
                "status" => "departure",
            ],
        ];
```

The code for groupping attendances:

```
$attendances = collect($data);
        $groupedAttendances = [];
        $currentGroup = [];

        foreach ($attendances as $attendance) {
            if ($attendance->status === 'arrival') {
                if (!empty($currentGroup)) {
                    if (count($currentGroup) === 1 && $currentGroup[0]->status === 'arrival') {
                        // Handle night shift with no departure on the same day
                        $currentGroup[0]->night_shift = true;
                    }
                    $groupedAttendances[] = $currentGroup;
                    $currentGroup = [];
                }
            }

            $currentGroup[] = $attendance;
        }

        if (!empty($currentGroup)) {
            if (count($currentGroup) === 1 && $currentGroup[0]->status === 'arrival') {
                // Handle night shift with no departure on the same day
                $currentGroup[0]->night_shift = true;
            }
            $groupedAttendances[] = $currentGroup;
        }

        print_r($groupedAttendances);
```

Output results:

```
array:3 [▼ 
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1580 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-24"
      +"time": "11:00:00"
      +"status": "arrival"
    }
    1 => {#1581 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-24"
      +"time": "14:00:00"
      +"status": "departure"
    }
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1552 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-24"
      +"time": "22:00:00"
      +"status": "arrival"
    }
    1 => {#1579 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-25"
      +"time": "06:00:00"
      +"status": "departure"
    }
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1578 ▼
      +"id": 5
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-25"
      +"time": "10:00:00"
      +"status": "arrival"
    }
    1 => {#1577 ▼
      +"id": 6
      +"attendance_date": "2023-08-25"
      +"time": "18:00:00"
      +"status": "departure"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not explained in the question which two entries form attendance pairs. Only the comments 'Group 1' etc. give a hint. So my assumption is that they are to be grouped in pairs as they are appearing in the array (hence the use of array_chunk).

Data:

```
$attendances = [
  [
    'id'              => 1,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-24',
    'time'            => '11:00:00',
    'status'          => 'arrival'
  ],
  [
    'id'              => 2,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-24',
    'time'            => '14:00:00',
    'status'          => 'departure'
  ],
  [
    'id'              => 3,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-24',
    'time'            => '22:00:00',
    'status'          => 'arrival'
  ],
  [
    'id'              => 4,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-25',
    'time'            => '06:00:00',
    'status'          => 'departure'
  ],
  [
    'id'              => 5,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-25',
    'time'            => '10:00:00',
    'status'          => 'arrival'
  ],
  [
    'id'              => 6,
    'attendance_date' => '2023-08-25',
    'time'            => '18:00:00',
    'status'          => 'departure'
  ]
];
```

Code:

```
$result = [];

foreach (array_chunk($attendances, 2) as $item) {
  if ($item[0]['attendance_date'] === $item[1]['attendance_date']) {
    $result[$item[0]['attendance_date']][] = $item;
  } else {
    $result[$item[0]['attendance_date']][] = [
      $item[0],
      [
        'id'              => $item[0]['id'],
        'attendance_date' => $item[0]['attendance_date'],
        'time'            => '23:59:59',
        'status'          => 'end of day'
      ],
    ];
    $result[$item[1]['attendance_date']][] = [
      [
        'id'              => $item[1]['id'],
        'attendance_date' => $item[1]['attendance_date'],
        'time'            => '00:00:00',
        'status'          => 'start of day'
      ],
      $item[1]
    ];
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2023-08-24] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-24
                            [time] => 11:00:00
                            [status] => arrival
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-24
                            [time] => 14:00:00
                            [status] => departure
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-24
                            [time] => 22:00:00
                            [status] => arrival
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-24
                            [time] => 23:59:59
                            [status] => end of day
                        )

                )

        )

    [2023-08-25] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-25
                            [time] => 00:00:00
                            [status] => start of day
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-25
                            [time] => 06:00:00
                            [status] => departure
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-25
                            [time] => 10:00:00
                            [status] => arrival
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [attendance_date] => 2023-08-25
                            [time] => 18:00:00
                            [status] => departure
                        )

                )

        )

)
```